# Did Adobe Flash's EOL cause trains to stop running in China?

Tags: china, software, transportation

News website Apple Daily posted on Jan 17 a report, picked up widely on socials, that Adobe discontinuing Flash caused trains to stop running in Dalian, China: [As Adobe Flash stops running, so do some railroads in China](https://hk.appledaily.com/news/20210117/FLXATT4LKVBGVEBRLAECJPTCHM/).

> The railroad system in Dalian, northern China, collapsed citywide on Tuesday for up to 20 hours after the Adobe Flash programing [sic] software stopped running. [...] Staffers were reportedly unable to view train operation diagrams, formulate train sequencing schedules and arrange shunting plans.

However according to [the statement posted by the Dalian Train Depot](https://mp.weixin.qq.com/s/YmB5YGDscBQIkG0bzvACPQ) (Google translated version) on QQ (WeChat):

> Recently, some self-media published the information that "the suspension of Flash led to the direct paralysis of the train dispatching system" and "the complete paralysis of the Dalian railway system" is inconsistent with the facts. The railway department hereby clarifies that it is not the railway train dispatching system that is affected by the deactivation of Flash, but some computers newly purchased and installed with the latest Flash version of the Dalian train service depot cannot access the statistical current train system through a browser. According to the statistics of this section, the current train system has always been operating normally, the railway train dispatching system has been operating normally, and the railway transportation production has not been affected in any way.

(There is a [GitHub page](https://github.com/duty-machine/duty-machine/issues/4135) that apparently mirrors the--now deleted or at least inaccessible outside China QQ/WeChat page linked above.)

And a [Twitter thread](https://twitter.com/tony_zy/status/1349753446107328513) by Tony Lin, a journalist who broke the story, albeit in a slightly less sensational clickbaity manner

Comment: I do not have too much knowledge on this particular case, but just from my personal experience (lived and worked in HK for years and still visits from time to time): 1. The chance that a real Chinese government department/agency that will log their work on github is about the same that CIA will put their list of undercover agents onto wechat

Comment: ct'd 2.The chance of **some** Apple Daily's mainland China story being real is about the same as, say, Hogwarts really exists. Note I am not only pointing at this one news agency, from my understanding and most people I know in HK sharing pretty much same view, the whole HK political news industry is in quite a chaos stage, where **both** side are creating some real life fantasy to a level that, to quote one of my friend: "My father had to read Ming Pao (which was famous for its serialized novel section) for a good story, now I just grab any random newspaper and read the political commentary".

Comment: @tweray: that github account is apparently just some kind of news aggregator. They post various articles [mis]using the issue tracker. Here's a more recent one https://github.com/duty-machine/duty-machine/issues/5349 The latter it's just something they copied from Weibo.